# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-emnist (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python-emnist

Tags: python, tensorflow

On running command python -m pip install python-emnist , Getting error as follows:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-emnist (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-emnist

Please help and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here how to install it from Github -> readme

https://github.com/vitords/EMNIST-sandbox